# Defining a generic transform iterator for iterating over different container types

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I have a class along the following lines :

```
class ArraySim{

  public: 
     DataStructure* ds;
     ArraySim(bool which){
        if(true)
           ds = new STDMap();
        else 
           ds = new HashMap();
     }
     value_type& operator[](int idx){
          return ds->getValAtIndex(idx);
     }

     //define a  custom iterator type that can be used to iterate over both std::map and boost::unordered //map keys.
} 

class DataStructure{

    vitrual value_type& getValAtIndex(int idx)=0;
};

class STDMap: public DataStructure{
   //Class that wraps a std::map object and implements the virtual method to return the value against a //particular index(key)
};

class HashMap: publlic DataStructure{
    //Class that wraps a boost::unordered_map object and implements the virtual method to return the value //against a particular index(key)
}
```

I have been through : [Generic Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938/generic-iterator) and [Transform Iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) . As I understand it , transform iterator still requires you to give the underlying container iterator in the template arguments. So is there a way I can use transform iterator to define a custom iterator type around the map keys and at the the same time make it work for different types of map containers ?

Comment: You can erase the type, like boost::any_iterator does (from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Boost, you can use [`any_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html).

```
typedef any_range<value_type, boost::forward_pass_traversal_tag,
  value_type &, std::ptrdiff_t> range;
typedef any_range<value_type, boost::forward_pass_traversal_tag,
  const value_type &, std::ptrdiff_t> const_range;
typedef range::iterator iterator;
typedef const_range::const_iterator const_iterator;

virtual iterator begin() = 0;
virtual iterator end() = 0;
virtual const_iterator begin() const = 0;
virtual const_iterator end() const = 0;
```

Your `begin` and `end` virtuals just need to construct the appropriate iterator:

```
iterator begin() { return iterator(object.begin()); }
```

Comment: Note that there's a good chance you *don't* want the `reference` type to be `value_type` but `value_type&`. Also, this doesn't accomodate `const` ranges correctly.

Comment: Still doesn't work correctly for `const` ranges, since `value_type const&` isn't convertible to `value_type&` (hint: you need two typedefs).